# Обёртка для круглой картинки заполняется наполовину. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css

Встречал мнение, что при вёрстке круглых картинок размеры задаются обёртке, а не самой картинке. Выходит наполовину заполненная обёртка. Как это исправить?

```css
.avatar-wrap {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
.avatar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-wrap">
  <img alt="img-name" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="avatar">
</div>
```

При добавлении : `height: 100%`, картинка некрасиво растягивается.

Дополнение: 
Указанный мною способ всё-таки работает, но только  для квадратных картинок и для картинок , которые по вертикали больше, чем по горизонтали.  В остальных случаях, видимо, необходимо использовать  другие способы. Спасибо за ответы!

```css
.avatar-wrap {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
.avatar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-wrap">
  <img alt="img-name" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/sports/" class="avatar">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

ПРоблема в том, что Вы ставите на картинке `width: 100%;`, тогда в высоту она меньше.

Предлагаю поставить картинку как `background` вот так:

```css
.avatar-wrap {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-wrap" style="background-image: URL(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);">  
 </div>
```